# 2 dynamically loaded divs side by side

Tags: css, api, html, instagram

I am creating an application using Instagram's API, and a series of DIVs

Wrapper,
Image Container,
   Image,
   PopUp (hover)
   user profile image
   user name
   date image was taken

I am hoping to have the Profile image, user name, and image displayed all on one line.

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nAfxc/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a width for your `.instagram` class.

See the jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nAfxc/3/).
In this case, I just put 10,000px as an example; you might want to calculate the actual number. May be something like this:

```
function SetWidth() {

  var WidthOfSinglePic = $('.instagram-feed').width();
  var NumberOfPicsInFeed = $('.instagram').find('.instagram-feed').length;
  var WidthOfParentDiv = parseInt(WidthOfSinglePic  * NumberOfPicsInFeed, 10);

  $('.instagram').width(WidthOfParentDiv);
}
```

**Edit: to remove the `<br>` tags**, this would do the trick:

```
$('.igHoverContent').each(function () {

  var ContentHTML = $(this).html();

  var CleanContent = ContentHTML.find('br').each(function() {
      $(this).remove();
  }); 

  $(this).html(CleanContent);

});
```

**Edit, after clarification:**

```
$('.igHoverContent').each(function () {

   var ThumbnaiTopPosition = $(this).parent().find('igHover2').position().top;
   var ThumbnaiLeftPosition = $(this).parent().find('igHover2').position().left;
   var ThumbnailWidth = $(this).parent().find('img').width();

   var NewLeftPostion = ThumbnaiLeftPosition + ThumbnailWidth;

   $(this).css({
      'top': ThumbnaiTopPosition,
      'left': NewLeftPostion  
   });
});
```

Note: when you say *"I am hoping to have the Profile image, user name, and image displayed all on one line."*, how is anyone supposed to guess that you really mean *"I want to position each class `.igHover` next to class `.igHoverProfPic`"?*

**Final Edit: I just figured out there was something very wrong with the HTML you're generating!!!** You should remove the closing tag of this: `<div class='igHoverContent' />\` so that the data is enclosed into the tag instead of being out of the tag!!!; and then just change your CSS to this:

```
.igHoverContent {
position: absolute;
margin: 275px 0px 0px 63px;}
```

**See the final output here: http://jsfiddle.net/nAfxc/6/**

Comment: Not what I am looking for, in my web app the images show up as I want, it's the Posted By, Posted On, and Profile Photo I am looking to align in one row.

Comment: What's supposed to happen when these don't all fit within the picture? I guess if you remove the <br> tag that's splitting your string then they'd be on the same line no?

Comment: I don't think that'll happen. Everything has set widths, the font, profile photo, etc...

You can see it live at: http://crookedspaces.com

Comment: Well then all you need to do is remove the <br> tag inside the "igHoverContent" class. I'd be skeptical about your assumption because if "Juan Marco Maria De La Fuente Sagrada" were to post a pic, then that would overflow.

Comment: Good point, I'll think about that, design wise.

However, that still wont work. I want the Profile photo DIV to be on the same line as "Posted By" and "Posted On" DIV

Comment: As a design suggestion, I would move the 'igHoverContent' class into the igHoverProfPic, to the right of the user's thumbnail. As it is, the text is in black and doesn't show when the background is also black.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am trying to do, thats what this thread is trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ah ok, now what you're trying to do is more clear! See update (in a second)

Comment: Seems like a complicated way to change something that should be an inherit CSS fix, no?

Comment: No, you're dealing with absolutely positioned elements, so floats don't work.

Comment: See the final update: you had a tag closed wrong! You can mark the answer as accepted if it works like you need it.

Comment: Goddammit! Closed a tag wrong, ha. Ain't that always the case.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Well glad we found it! Happy coding!